# Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s) when creating Powershell dictionary

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a dictionary from the following file hostname.csv:

```
hostname        type
LON131          gaming
LON132          gaming
LON133          research
LON134          research
```

using the below Powershell script:

```
get-content hostname.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($dict.Keys -contains $_.type) {
        $dict[$_.type]+=$_.hostname
    } else {
        $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
    }
}

Write-Host $dict;
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At fcheck.ps1:7 char:29
+         $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At fcheck.ps1:7 char:29
+         $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At fcheck.ps1:7 char:29
+         $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At fcheck.ps1:7 char:29
+         $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At fcheck.ps1:7 char:29
+         $dict.Add($_.type,@($_.hostname))
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

What could be causing it and how do I go about resolving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try replacing `get-content hostname.csv` with:

```
Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -Path hostname.csv
```

EDIT:

I think you might not be initializing `dict` priro to calling `$dict.keys`. The following worked for me:

```
$dict = @{} 
Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($dict.Keys -contains $_.type) {
        $dict[$_.type]+=$_.hostname
    } else {
        $dict[$_.type] = @($_.hostname)
    }
}

$dict
```

Comment: I now get the following error message `Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null. At fcheck.ps1:7 char:28`

Answer (score 2):

"Key cannot be null." - `$_.type` does not evaluate to what is expected. ([`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx) returns *lines of text* and doesn't know anything about CSV files/columns.)

The error message is misleading in that the problem has nothing to do with the number of arguments; this is just PowerShell providing some details about the dynamic method call.

In any case, barring the issue noted above, the `Add` could be rewritten as `$dict[$_.type] = @($_.hostname)` for uniformity. Of course the CSV data needs to be correctly read first.

Comment: @methuselah Verify what values `$_` (and `$_.type`) evaluate to in the `ForEach-Object`. As noted, `$_.type` is evaluating to `null` (which `Add` is rejecting as a key) - so then find out *why* it's the case :) Hint: what is the result of `Get-Content`?